# Ruby hiding API keys and IP address?

Tags: ruby

I have a ruby script `main.rb` which takes in two parameters, `ipaddress` and `apitoken`.

```
$token = "VALUE"
$ip_addr = "ADDRESS"
```

These values are hard coded into the script. When I push the project into Github's repo, I get a warning that my keys are visible.

What is the recommended way to hide these variables? Is it as simple as adding a separate file for these values and adding them to `.gitignore`?

Comment: Couldn't you just remove them from your github repo?

Comment: A common good way is to get these values from environment variables, i.e `$token = ENV['TOKEN']` and so.

Comment: @the12 yes, but suppose I would like to edit the files, I would have to remove them every time before pushing.

Answer (score 1):

Personally, I don't like using `open` and file operations in code. Better way would be to use one of the following approaches,

Put the keys in system environment as follows,

```
export MY_TOKEN=xyz
export MY_IP_ADDR=a.b.c.d
```

If you want it to be available after you restart shell, then put it in `~/.bash_profile`.

and in your code use as follows,

```
$token = ENV["MY_TOKEN"]
$ip_addr = ENV["MY_IP_ADDR"]
```

**OR**

You can use [dotenv gem](https://github.com/bkeepers/dotenv), if you don't want system wide environment variables and exclude `.env` from git but putting the file in `.gitignore`.

Answer (score 0):

Following this [guide](http://gregeng.github.io/blog/2013/11/21/hide-your-keys/), a simple way to do this is to create folders `.auth_token` and `.ip_addr`.

Add the necessary keys in them and access them by reading the files as follows:

```
$token = open("lib/assets/.auth_token").read()
$ip_addr = open("lib/assets/.ip_addr").read()
```

If pushing to a repository, make sure the folders are added to `.gitignore`